# How implement this flowchart

Tags: c#

How implement this flowchart see attached image by  using ASP.NET with C# 
[flow chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ziB6.png)When the application server
received input from the user, it dynamically generated the query based on the input. This
query, along with the developer-intended query made use of keyword randomization, where
the randomly generated key was appended to the SQL keywords in both queries. These
queries were then forwarded to an XML parsing component, which converted both queries
into XML trees. These XML parse trees were compared, and based on the result of comparison,
the algorithm was able to determine whether the dynamically built query was an attack
or not. If this query was non-malicious, it was allowed to pass further to the database server
for execution. However, if the algorithm determined a query as an attack, it was blocked
at the application server and was not sent to the database server for execution. The attack
queries were added to an error log to help the system administrators to review them.

Comment: You need an XML Schema to validate the XML requests.

Answer (score 0):

I want to design this flow char for sql injection prevention

[image]